# Assigning newlines to a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that manipulates files with Windows newlines. In the simplest case, I want to output a file with three lines, like this:

```
one
two
three
```

This script works correctly:

```
echo -n one$'\r'$'\n'two$'\r'$'\n'three$'\r'$'\n' > Readme.txt
```

But when I assign the text to a variable, it fails. It retains the `\r`, but converts each `\n` into a space:

```
foo="$(echo -n one$'\r'$'\n'two$'\r'$'\n'three$'\r'$'\n')"
echo $foo > Readme.txt
```

So how can I assign a variable in such a way that it will retain newlines?

(Notice the `-n`, which prevents "echo" from appending a Unix-style newline.)

Comment: Use `printf` with the full string: `printf "one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\n"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: Without quotes (`echo "$foo"`) the contents of `foo` undergo word splitting.